# How to remove the padding where a div isn't showing

Tags: css, html

I'm having a trouble to remove the padding of some of my divs I've created fpr the main page, but when I hide the div in other pages like in the about us page the padding of the hidden divs is still showing. here is the website I'm working on http://mem-stockholm.se

As you can see in the main menu a div called bottom has a padding of 70 px.

[pic 1](http://www.mem-stockholm.se/host/capture%203.PNG)

And on others subpages like the about us "om oss" where the bottom div is hidden in the options in joomla the padding still showing.

[pic 2](http://mem-stockholm.se/host/Capture.PNG)

I've tried to use a reset CSS but I'm getting the same issue.

this is my THML

```
<html>

<head>

      <base href="http://mem-stockholm.se/" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="generator" content="Joomla! - Open Source Content Management" />
  <title>MeM Stockholm - HEM</title>
  <link href="http://mem-stockholm.se/" rel="canonical" />
  <link href="/templates/memstockholm/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/memstockholm/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/memstockholm/css/component.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/media/system/css/modal.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/modules/mod_slideshowck/themes/default/css/camera.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans" type="text/css" />
  <style type="text/css">
#camera_wrap_94 .camera_pag_ul li img, #camera_wrap_94 .camera_thumbs_cont ul li > img {height:75px;}
#camera_wrap_94 .camera_caption {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
#camera_wrap_94 .camera_caption > div {
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;-webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;font-size: 12px;font-family:'Droid Sans';
}
#camera_wrap_94 .camera_caption > div div.slideshowck_description {
    font-size: 10px;
}

  </style>
  <script src="/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/media/jui/js/jquery-noconflict.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/media/jui/js/jquery-migrate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/media/system/js/caption.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/templates/memstockholm/js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/templates/memstockholm/js/snap.svg-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/media/system/js/mootools-core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/media/system/js/core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/media/system/js/mootools-more.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/media/system/js/modal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/modules/mod_slideshowck/assets/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/modules/mod_slideshowck/assets/jquery.mobile.customized.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/modules/mod_slideshowck/assets/camera.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).on('load',  function() {
                new JCaption('img.caption');
            });
        window.addEvent('domready', function() {

            SqueezeBox.initialize({});
            SqueezeBox.assign($$('a.modal'), {
                parse: 'rel'
            });
        });
  </script>


</head>

<body>

    <div id="main" class="main">
        <div id="top" class="top">
            <div id="logo" class="">
                <a href="http://mem-stockholm.se">
                    <img src="/templates/memstockholm/img/logo.png" alt="MeM Stockholm Logo" title="MeM Stockholm Logo" style=" width: 240px" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="menu" class="">
                <ul class="nav menu" id="Menu">
<li class="item-101 current active"><a href="/" >HEM</a></li><li class="item-107 divider deeper parent"><span class="separator">
    PRIVAT</span>
<ul class="nav-child unstyled small"><li class="item-110"><a href="/privat/hemstädning.html" >Hemstädning</a></li><li class="item-113"><a href="/privat/flyttstädning.html" >Flyttstädning </a></li><li class="item-111"><a href="/privat/storstädning.html" >Storstädning </a></li><li class="item-125"><a href="/privat/fönsterputsning.html" >Fönsterputsning </a></li></ul></li><li class="item-122 divider deeper parent"><span class="separator">
    FÖRETAG</span>
<ul class="nav-child unstyled small"><li class="item-123"><a href="/2015-04-02-22-05-44/kontorsstädning.html" >Kontorsstädning</a></li><li class="item-124"><a href="/2015-04-02-22-05-44/skolstädning.html" >Skolstädning</a></li><li class="item-112"><a href="/2015-04-02-22-05-44/trappstädning.html" >Trappstädning</a></li></ul></li><li class="item-108"><a href="/om-oss.html" >OM OSS</a></li><li class="item-109"><a href="/kontakt.html" >KONTAKT</a></li></ul>

            </div>
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
        </div>


        <div id="" class="slide">

        <!--[if lte IE 7]>
        <link href="/modules/mod_slideshowck/themes/default/css/camera_ie.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <![endif]-->
        <!--[if IE 8]>
        <link href="/modules/mod_slideshowck/themes/default/css/camera_ie8.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <![endif]--><script type="text/javascript"> <!--
       jQuery(function(){
        jQuery('#camera_wrap_94').camera({
                height: '499',
                minHeight: '',
                pauseOnClick: false,
                hover: 1,
                fx: 'random',
                loader: 'pie',
                pagination: 0,
                thumbnails: 0,
                thumbheight: 75,
                thumbwidth: 100,
                time: 7000,
                transPeriod: 1500,
                alignment: 'center',
                autoAdvance: 1,
                mobileAutoAdvance: 1,
                portrait: 0,
                barDirection: 'leftToRight',
                imagePath: '/modules/mod_slideshowck/images/',
                lightbox: 'mediaboxck',
                fullpage: 0,
                mobileimageresolution: '0',
                navigationHover: true,
                navigation: true,
                playPause: true,
                barPosition: 'bottom',
                container: ''
        });
}); //--> </script><!-- debut Slideshow CK -->
<div class="slideshowck camera_wrap camera_ash_skin" id="camera_wrap_94" style="width:960px;">
            <div data-thumb="/images/MeM_kev/th/slide1_th.jpg" data-src="/images/MeM_kev/slide1.jpg" >
                    </div>
        <div data-thumb="/images/MeM_kev/th/slide2_th.jpg" data-src="/images/MeM_kev/slide2.jpg" >
                    </div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<!-- fin Slideshow CK -->

        </div>

        <div id="MainContent">
            <div class="item-page">




                                <h1 style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 24pt;">Vi st&auml;dar &aring;t b&aring;de f&ouml;retag och privatpersoner i Stockholm </span></h1>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">Gillar du, precis som jag, att komma hem till ett rent och fr&auml;scht hem efter en l&aring;ng dag p&aring; jobbet? Att f&aring; vistas p&aring; en plats d&auml;r du kan ladda batterierna igen? Oavsett om det g&auml;ller hemmet eller arbetsplatsen &auml;r det allm&auml;nt k&auml;nt att oreda och smuts &auml;r distraherande p&aring; ett mycket negativt s&auml;tt. Och alla vet vi hur sk&ouml;nt det &auml;r att vistas i en ren milj&ouml;, och hur tr&aring;kigt och tidskr&auml;vande det &auml;r att skapa denna p&aring; egen hand.</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">Detta &auml;r vi p&aring; MeM i Stockholm mycket medvetna om och erbjuder d&auml;rf&ouml;r st&auml;dhj&auml;lp i Stockholm av alla de slag som du kan utnyttja och s&aring;ledes f&aring; tid &ouml;ver till roligare saker &auml;n st&auml;dning. Hos oss arbetar endast speciellt utvalda st&auml;derskor som vi &auml;ven utbildar p&aring; egen hand, s&aring; att du som kund kan vara s&auml;ker p&aring; att f&aring; kompetent, p&aring;litlig och lyh&ouml;rd st&auml;dhj&auml;lp, antingen i hemmet eller p&aring; kontoret.</p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><br />MeM i Stockholm &auml;r det personliga st&auml;df&ouml;retaget i Stockholm med fokus p&aring; kundens behov och &ouml;nskem&aring;l. Genom att erbjuda ett komplett utbud av st&auml;dtj&auml;nster hoppas vi kunna hj&auml;lpa dig oberoende vilken st&auml;dhj&auml;lp du beh&ouml;ver</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><a href="/om-oss.html" class="button1">more</a></p>

                         </div>

        </div>
  </div> <!-- this is the new div-->
        <div id="services" class="">


<div class="custom"  >
    <div class="container">
<section id="grid" class="grid clearfix">
<a href="/privat/hemstädning.html" data-path-hover="m 180,34.57627 -180,0 L 0,0 180,0 z">
<figure>
<img src="/images/1.png" alt="" /> 
<svg viewBox="0 0 180 320" preserveAspectRatio="none"><path d="M 180,160 0,218 0,0 180,0 z"/></svg>
<figcaption>
<h2>Hemstädning</h2>
<p> Med hemstädning från oss får du tid över till annat för en låg kostnad</p>
</figcaption>
</figure>
</a>
<a href="/privat/flyttstädning.html" data-path-hover="m 180,34.57627 -180,0 L 0,0 180,0 z">
<figure><img src="/images/3.png" alt="" /> 
<svg viewBox="0 0 180 320" preserveAspectRatio="none"><path d="M 180,160 0,218 0,0 180,0 z"/></svg>
<figcaption>
<h2>Fyttstädning</h2>
<p>lägga allt fokus på det nya boendet istället</p>
</figcaption></figure>
</a>
<a href="http://mem-stockholm.se/privat/fönsterputsning.html" data-path-hover="m 180,34.57627 -180,0 L 0,0 180,0 z">
<figure><img src="/images/5.png" alt="" />
<svg viewBox="0 0 180 320" preserveAspectRatio="none"><path d="M 180,160 0,218 0,0 180,0 z"/></svg>
<figcaption>
<h2>Fönsterputsning</h2>
<p>Njut av utsikten genom rena fönster</p>
</figcaption></figure>
</a>
<a href="http://mem-stockholm.se/2015-04-02-22-05-44/kontorsstädning.html" data-path-hover="m 180,34.57627 -180,0 L 0,0 180,0 z">
<figure><img src="/images/7.png" alt="" />
<svg viewBox="0 0 180 320" preserveAspectRatio="none"><path d="M 180,160 0,218 0,0 180,0 z"/></svg>
 <figcaption>
<h2>Kontorstädning</h2>
<p>I dagsläget hjälper vi en rad små o medelstora företag med att hålla rent på kontoret</p>
</figcaption></figure>
</a>
</section>
</div>
<!-- /container -->
<script>
            (function() {

                function init() {
                    var speed = 250,
                        easing = mina.easeinout;

                    [].slice.call ( document.querySelectorAll( '#grid > a' ) ).forEach( function( el ) {
                        var s = Snap( el.querySelector( 'svg' ) ), path = s.select( 'path' ),
                            pathConfig = {
                                from : path.attr( 'd' ),
                                to : el.getAttribute( 'data-path-hover' )
                            };

                        el.addEventListener( 'mouseenter', function() {
                            path.animate( { 'path' : pathConfig.to }, speed, easing );
                        } );

                        el.addEventListener( 'mouseleave', function() {
                            path.animate( { 'path' : pathConfig.from }, speed, easing );
                        } );
                    } );
                }

                init();

            })();
        </script></div>

        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>

        <div id="bottom" class="">

            <div id="" class="user1">

            </div>

            <div id="" class="user2">


<div class="custom"  >
    <h2><span style="color: #333333;">RUT - avdrag</span></h2>
<p>Gl&ouml;m inte skattereduktion av hush&aring;llsn&auml;ra tj&auml;nster! Fr&aring;n och med den 1 juli 2009 g&auml;ller nya regler - nu f&aring;r du r&auml;tt till 50% skattereduktion&nbsp;p&aring; alla v&aring;ra tj&auml;nster</p>
<p><br /><a href="http://www.skatteverket.se/privat/fastigheterbostad/rotrutarbete.4.2e56d4ba1202f95012080002966.html" class="button1">more</a></p></div>

            </div>

            <div id="" class="user3">


<div class="custom"  >
    <h2><span style="color: #333333;">Alltid Samma St&auml;derska</span>
</h2>
<p>Vi ser till att du alltid f&aring;r samma st&auml;derska vid varje st&auml;dtillf&auml;llet. Allt f&ouml;r att du ska k&auml;nna dig trygg och bekv&auml;m och veta att st&auml;dningen sk&ouml;ts p&aring; det s&auml;tt du vill att den ska sk&ouml;tas.</p>
<p><br /><a href="http://mem-stockholm.se/kontakt.html" class="button1">Beställ</a>
</p></div>

            </div>
         <div style="clear:both"></div>   
        </div>

   <!-- </div> -->
    <div id="map" class="maps">


<div class="custom"  >
    <p><iframe style="border: 0;" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2039.0955892513716!2d18.04974819999999!3d59.26455200000001!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x465f7762172c02eb%3A0xfe9518caa70f4f90!2sSt%C3%A5lbogav%C3%A4gen+36%2C+124+56+Bandhagen!5e0!3m2!1ssv!2sse!4v1428093376978" width="960" height="300" frameborder="0"></iframe></p></div>

    </div>
    <div id="footer" class="footer">
        MEM Stockholm &copy; 2015 All rights reserved | Designed by <a href="https://www.facebook.com/punkeb" target="_blank">Kevin Gr. Z</a><br/>
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

and this is my CSS

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,100);

body {
    padding-top:10px;
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #333333;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height:25px;

}

#top{
    padding-top: 40px;

}



#logo{
    float: left;
}

#menu
{
    margin-top:15px;
    float: right;
    font-weight: 400;
    position: relative;
    z-index:1000;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:13px;
    line-height:32px;
    padding:0 15px;

}

#menu li.current {
    color:#fff;  
}


#menu ul
{
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#menu ul a
{
    display:block;
    color:#333333;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:13px;
    padding:0px;
}

#menu ul li
{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

#menu ul li ul li:hover {

    background:#fff;
}
#menu ul li ul li { 
  background: #34646B; 
  display: block;

}
#menu a:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #34646B;
}

#menu ul ul
{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
    background:#fff;
    padding:0;
}

#menu ul ul li
{
    float:none;
    width:125px;
}

#menu ul ul a
{
    line-height:120%;
    padding:10px 15px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 300;
}

#menu ul ul ul
{
    top:0;
    left:100%;
}

#menu ul li:hover > ul
{
    display:block;

}

.slide{
    padding: 45px 0px 60px;

}

.button1, .button2, .button3  {
    background-color:#333333;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:300;
    font-style:normal;
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    width:100px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    -webkit-transition-property: background;
       -moz-transition-property: background;
         -o-transition-property: background;
            transition-property: background;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
       -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
         -o-transition-duration: 1s;
            transition-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
       -moz-transition-timing-function: linear;
         -o-transition-timing-function: linear;
            transition-timing-function: linear;
}

.button1:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
.button1:hover {
    background-color:#34646B;
}


#services{
    padding: 60px 0px;

}

#bottom{
    padding: 70px 0px;
}


.user2{
    float: left;
    width: 450px;
}

.user3{
    float: right;
    width: 480px;
}

.user2, .user3{
    color: #505050;
    font-weight: 100;

}


#map{
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.maps {
        position: relative;
        height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;

    }
.maps iframe {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100% !important;
        height: 300px;
    }

#footer{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #505050;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;


}

#footer a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #34646B;

}
```

Comment: I am not too familiar with Joomla but can you add a class to the body of the page similar to that of WordPress where the body has a class of the page-id or template? If you can do that then you could target each page and "display: none" the bottom ID

Answer (score 0):

if you could make this div like:

```
<div id="bottom" class="pagename"> $content </div>
```

you then could assign it a special treatment in CSS file like this

```
#bottom {
  padding 70px 0px;
}
.pagename {  //just to give it a name, no swedish here. :)
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@import is known to cause trouble at times. Try to reference the sheet via link rel in the head section to check if the problem persists. Else, that particular sheet may have a life of its own, e.g. overriding or locking some values one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

I think the good solution to this problem is in the modification of the template.

In a joomla template, you can determine, which is the part of your html is shown and what is not, depending on whether the module is included in the page, or not.
This is achieved by PHP.

I Leave a basic example of how to do it in your template index.php

It can also improve the function using else, for example.

```
<?php  if($this->countModules('botton')) : ?>
 <div id="botton" class="botton-class">
   <jdoc:include type="modules" name="botton" style="block" />
 </div>
<?php  endif; ?>
```